# If statements to fulfill conditions relating to dates

Tags: r, for-loop, datetime, if-statement

I'm trying to manipulate the data with these dates.

**Condition: if start time and end time overlaps with previous date from 21:00 to 9:00 next day, then the correct date would be the previous date.**

For example here: Obs 3: the start time 12/5/2020 9:27 and end time 12/5/2020 12:13 overlaps with 12/4/2020 21:00 to 12/5/2020 10:00. So the correct date should be 12/04/2020.
[image]

With this logic, the next step is to combine hrs_slept for example Obs 6 and 7 because they have the same dates, which would become:

**Condition: for each ID, if there are same dates, hrs_slept need to be combined:**
[image]

original:

```
start_time <- c("2020-12-02 23:01:00","2020-12-04 04:17:00","2020-12-05 09:27:00","2020-12-06 06:38:00","2020-12-06 11:42:00","2020-12-08 01:22:00","2020-12-08 05:33:00", "2020-12-08 16:59:00","2020-12-09 03:15:00")
end_time <- c("2020-12-03 01:03:00","2020-12-04 09:42:00","2020-12-05 12:13:00","2020-12-06 09:16:00","2020-12-06 14:50:00","2020-12-08 04:24:00","2020-12-08 06:37:00","2020-12-08 18:05:00","2020-12-09 06:21:00")
hrs_sleep <- c(2.03,5.42,2.77,2.63,3.13,3.03,1.07,1.10,3.10)
a <- data.frame(start_time,end_time,hrs_sleep)%>%
  mutate(ID=104)
a$start <- as.POSIXct(a$start)
a$end <- as.POSIXct(a$end)
```

Desired:

```
start_date <- c("2020-12-02","2020-12-03","2020-12-04","2020-12-05","2020-12-06","2020-12-07","2020-12-08")
hrs_sleep_new <- c(2.03,5.42,2.77,2.63,3.13,4.10,4.20)
b <- data.frame(start_date,hrs_sleep_new)%>%
  mutate(ID=104)
b$start_date <- as.POSIXct(b$start_date)
```

I hope I made the logic clear. Essentially, I just need some sort of if statements for the two conditions written in bold. And I have a lot more observations with different IDs so these conditions need to be for each ID.

I appreciate all the help there is! Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you subtract 9 hours and take the date of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand the conditions. However, try this code:

a <- a %>% mutate(start_date = as.Date(ifelse(hour(start) < 10, date(start)-1,date(start)), origin = "1970-01-01")) # Create the dates

a %>% group_by(ID, start_date) %>% summarise(hrs_sleep_new = sum(hrs_sleep)) # Sum the sleep hours

Comment: Thanks, this actually works to my intention. Would you mind explaining what the 10 means?

Comment: Of course! The code tests if the hour of the start is less than 10am (as you wrote above), that is, if the person started to sleep before 10am. If so, the correct value to the start_date is the day before, otherwise it's the same day. In order to format the date, I had to use the "origin" argument, just to set the first day in the calendar (the result without it is a number around 18600). 
If you need to add other conditions, use & for "and" and | for "or" in the first argument of ifelse (eg: ifelse((hour(start) < 10)&(hour(end)<10),...) tests if both are less than 10am.